# How do I implicitly link to a dll and its dependencies without conflict?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, loadlibrary

I have a dll A that [implicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) links to a dll Z. dll A also [explicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) links to a dll B, which [implicitly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) links to dll Z' (a different version of the Z dll).

Some additional factors are:
dll B can be located anywhere in the system, its location is revealed to dll A at runtime through an XML file, and it is loaded using loadlibrary.

Due to restrictions beyond our control, we are not able to change the environment path.

The problem I have is ensuring dlls A and B use the correct versions of the Z dll.

What options do I have?

Comment: You're hosed. You cannot load two different versions of the same library "implicitly" (I would call this "without using `dlopen`"), period full stop. If the libraries aren't PIC this would require two different sets of symbols to be in the same virtual address space, which is clearly impossible.

Comment: Essentially your only option is to externalize one of the two into a separate process, such as an out of process COM server.

Comment: Thanks guys, if you post an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: I believe that's what COM was invented for. Do you have access to Don Box's [Essential COM](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0201634465)? The first chapter does a wonderful job of framing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by modifying the manifest of one of the two A or B so that they both link against the same version of Z. The manifest is likely embedded and so you'll need Microsoft's Manifest Tool mt.exe which should be available with the SDK. This happens frequently when you link against 3 party tools that were linked against a different runtime than the one that you use.